# Html button to red

Tags: html

I have a button

```
<button name="" class="btn-primary" type="object"/>
```

and it's showing in blue color.How can I change this button to RED color?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? If so you can use class `btn-danger` or `btn-error`, not sure.

Comment: Also, type object? where did you get this from

Comment: Side note: the `button` tag can't be self-closing. It should always have a starting and ending tag.

Comment: thanks the btn-danger worked

Comment: @Mqondisi  Hey, hopping in real quick to check whether I solved your issue or do I need to ameliorate my skills?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using bootstrap:

```
<button name="" class="btn btn-danger" type="object"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the class of button to **danger** like `<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>`this and your button will be changed to red.

It will surely solve your issue and if it doesn't let me know in the comments, I will try my best to help you.

Answer (score -1):

you can use inline styling inside the button tag

like this

```
<button name="" class="btn-primary" type="object" style="backgound-color:red"/>
```